# Can we reopen this question?

Tags: discussion

There is a [question by Evan Carroll](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean) about the origins of "sargable" that initially had received some "tough love" and got closed as off-topic. I was among those who voted to close it (as too localized), at the time it looked to me more like a rant.

Recently I saw it in the "Reopen" queue, and now, after having been helpfully edited by Jack Douglas, it seems more appropriate and actually answerable.

I did some research of my own and I think I might have a pretty definitive answer to the question as stated now. I voted to reopen the question but it needs more votes.

Can we please reopen the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. Reasonable request, looks decent.